# Mockito inline Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type

Tags: mockito, mockito-inline

I am facing the following issue no matter what version of mockito I use:
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:

Mockito cannot mock this class: class org.apache.commons.lang.text.StrLookup.

If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please open an issue on GitHub.

Java               : 11
JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
JVM vendor version : 11.0.22+9-LTS-219
JVM name           : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 11.0.22+9-LTS-219
JVM info           : mixed mode
OS name            : Linux
OS version         : 5.10.102.2-microsoft-standard

You are seeing this disclaimer because Mockito is configured to create inlined mocks.
You can learn about inline mocks and their limitations under item #39 of the Mockito class javadoc.

Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type
at com.vorwerk.aem.global.email.AbstractEmailActionTest.(AbstractEmailActionTest.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type
at com.vorwerk.aem.global.email.AbstractEmailActionTest.(AbstractEmailActionTest.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError
at com.vorwerk.aem.global.email.AbstractEmailActionTest.(AbstractEmailActionTest.java:38)

I tried changing the version of mockito and also moving to mockito-core to mockito-bom

Comment: Did you read [item #39 of the Mockito class javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39) as suggested by the error message?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.